# Transfer database from SQL Server 2008 version 10.50.2500 to 10.0 2531

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I cannot believe this is so difficult. Backup / Restore fails. Import and Export both fail with a variety of silly errors.

Is there a way to do this that works?

Comment: why does the restore fail?

Comment: Restore fails because backup was made using version 10.50.2500 and trying to do restore using version 10.0.2531

Answer (score 0):

Try scripting out the schema and data, with the SQL Server Management Studio

[Article explaining how to use SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.icodefor.net/2014/07/how-to-generate-insert-scripts-and-in-sql-server.html)

If that doesn't work, you'll have to use a more advanced third party tool. Like, for instance, Red Gate's Sql Toolbelt, where:

1. SQL Compare allows you to compare and merge schema between 2 databases
2. Data Compare allows you to compare and merge data between 2 databases